# How to get to end of line but before start of comment in emacs C++ mode?

Tags: c++, emacs

In practice I usually encounter below situation:

```
statement_line /*..some comments..*/
```

Sometimes I need to jump to **just pass the end** of the statement_line to: add some code, or delete the entire comment region.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to do it? (I know <kbd>C-s ; Ret</kbd> works for statement_line ending with a ";" but this is not all the case. e.g. `if(...) /*...comments...*/`)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```lisp
(defun end-of-statement ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)
  (if (comment-search-forward (line-end-position) t)
      (re-search-backward "//\\|/\\*")
    (end-of-line))
  (skip-chars-backward " \t"))
```

I just wrote it, so it might require some tweaks, but it looks
fine at the moment.

Comment: After some further testing, it is found that the below case won't work: when the cursor is inside the comment region. Wish this can be fixed.

Comment: Fine, a call to `beginning-of-line` at the start should fix it.

Comment: Obviously this code only works for C/C++-style comments.  This is silly since `comment-search-forward` already did the hard part: it returns the position of the beginning of the comment.  So just `(goto-char (or (comment-search-forward (line-end-position) t) (line-end-position))` should do the trick.

Comment: Nope. The position resulting from your code is not the desired one. I don't know of generic code that provides the desired position, hence the ad-hoc stuff:)

Comment: Actually, it should be, safe for whitespace.  So just add a `(skip-chars-backward " \t")` and you should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer to your question, but for the case where you want to remove the comment, you can use `C-u M-;` (aka `comment-kill`).

Comment: GOod point. This is the 1st time I learned about the flagging prefix C-u. Are there any other useful flagged commands worth mentioning?

Answer (score 1):

I have a command to bounce between the end of line and end of code.  It works in most programming modes.

```
(defun end-of-line-code ()
  (interactive "^")
  (require 'newcomment)
  (if comment-start-skip
      (save-match-data
        (let* ((bolpos (line-beginning-position)))
          (end-of-line)
          (if (comment-search-backward bolpos 'noerror)
              (search-backward-regexp comment-start-skip bolpos 'noerror))
          (skip-syntax-backward " " bolpos)))
    (end-of-line)))

(defun end-of-line-or-code ()
  "Move to EOL, or if already there, to EOL sans comments."
  (interactive "^")
  (if (eolp) ;; test me here
      (end-of-line-code)
    (end-of-line)))
(put 'end-of-line-or-code 'CUA 'move)

(defun jpk/prog-mode-hook ()
  ...
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-e") 'end-of-line-or-code)
  ...
  )

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'jpk/prog-mode-hook)
```

I have a similar command that bounces between the beginning of line and beginning of text, which I can post if you're interested.